# R shiny Images not displaying after hosting on web

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I am trying to build my resume in R shiny, and have hosted the application as well, but the images which I have used are not displaying after the app getting hosted.

[Link of the app](https://mayanktripathi.shinyapps.io/RESUME/)

I have saved the images in the www folder.  below is the code.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rsconnect)

#

shinyUI(
    dashboardPage(
        skin = "blue",
        
        dashboardHeader(title = "MAYANK TRIPATHI", titleWidth = 500, disable = TRUE),
        
        dashboardSidebar(
            
            sidebarMenu(
                
                menuItem(text = "About", tabName = "about", icon =icon("clipboard")),
                menuItem(text = "Experience", tabName = "experience", icon =icon("fas fa-briefcase")),
                menuItem(text = "Certifications", tabName = "certifications", icon =icon("fas fa-star")),
                menuItem(text = "Skills", tabName = "skills", icon =icon("fas fa-plus")),
                menuItem(text = "Education", tabName = "education", icon =icon("fas fa-user-graduate")),
                menuItem(text = "Awards", tabName = "awards", icon =icon("fas fa-medal"))
                
            )
            
        ),
        
        dashboardBody(
            
            tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                /* body */
                .content-wrapper, .right-side {
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                }
                
                '))),
            
            tabItems(
                
                tabItem(tabName = "about",
                # tags$img(src='mayank.png',height=180,width = 150,style = 'float:right;'),
                HTML('<center><img src="mayank.png"></center>'),
                h2(p("MAYANK TRIPATHI"),align = "center"),
                h3(p("Supply Chain Operations Consultant . 5+ yrs Experience . 8767461837 . mayanktripathi014@gmail.com"),align = "center"),
                h3(p("Supply Chain Data Analytics | Process Improvement | Lean Management | Forecasting | Project Management "),align = "center"),
                br(),
                  h4(p("

                    A DATA LOVER who believes in ' making your data do the work for you'.
                    5+ years of experience working in the engineering and supply chain field. 
                    A result-oriented professional at synchronizing supply with demands and developing supply 
                    chain strategies that significantly 
                    impact profitability and increases the value of the business.
                    Strong written and spoken communication skills, ability to handle pressures arising from deadlines & targets.
                    Always keen on learning and implementing new skills at work for higher efficiency and greater impact.

                  "))),
                
                
                tabItem(tabName = "awards",
                    
                    h1(p("AWARDS & RECOGNITION"),align = "center"),
                    br(),
                    tags$img(src='cyber.png',height=200,width = 300,style = 'float:left;'),
                    h3(p("Received letter of appreciation from regional CEO, IMEA for exceptional contribution during 
                      the cyber-attack crises at the Maersk group.")),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    
                    tags$img(src='srf.png',height=200,width = 300,style = 'float:left;'),
                    h3(p("Received Letter of appreciation from SRF Limited one of the consignors of Walmart for going beyond the call 
                        of duty to be available to resolve unforeseen potential show-stoppers while handling their Haz Cargo")),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br()),
                    
                    
                
                
                tabItem(tabName = "education",
                    
                    h1(p("SCHOLASTIC RECORD"),align = "center"),
                    br(),
                    br(),

                    h3("Executive Development Program In Data Science "),
                    h4("XLRI Jamshedpur | First Class"),
                    
                    br(),
                    
                    h3("P.G.D.M - Operations Management"),
                    h4("Chetana's Institute of Management and Research | Grade 'A' "),
                    
                    br(),
                    
                    
                    h3("BE - Electronics Engineering"),
                    h4("Mumbai University | First Class"),
                    
                    br(),
                    
                    
                    h3("H.S.C."),
                    h4("Maharashtra Board | First Class"),
                    
                    br(),
                    
                    h3("S.S.C."),
                    h4("Maharashtra Board | First Class"),

                    br()
                    
                    ),
                
                
                
                tabItem(tabName = "skills",
                    
                    h1(p("Continuous Development In Skillset"),align = "center"),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    
                    tags$img(src='rstudio.png',height=90,width = 100,style = 'float:left;'),
                    h3(p("R Programming for statistical analysis, Data Analysis and Machine Learning")),
                    br(),
                    tags$img(src='shiny.png',height=90,width = 100,style = 'float:left;'),
                    h3(p("R shiny for building interactive web applications and Business excellence tools")),
                    br(),
                    tags$img(src='sql.png',height=90,width = 100,style = 'float:left;'),
                    h3(p("SQL for handling relational databases")),
                    br(),
                    tags$img(src='PBI.png',height=90,width = 100,style = 'float:left;'),
                    h3(p("Power BI for building Interactive Dynamic Dashboards")),
                    br(),
                    tags$img(src='tab.png',height=90,width = 100,style = 'float:left;'),
                    h3(p("Tableau for building Interactive Dynamic Dashboards")),
                    br(),
                    tags$img(src='xl.png',height=90,width = 100,style = 'float:left;'),
                    h3(p("Advance Excel for conducting data analysis, data visualization, and data storage"))),
                    
                    tabItem(tabName = "experience",
                    h1(p("PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE"),align = "center"),
                    br(),
                    tags$img(src='rsm.png',height=150,width = 150,style = 'float:right;'),
                    h1(p("RSM Astute Consulting Pvt Ltd")),
                    h4(p("June 2019 - Present")),
                    h3(em(p("Supply Chain Operations Consultant"))),
                    h4(p(" Developed a Zero-based Logistics Cost optimization model in R programming, 
                      to estimate the optimum freight rate / benchmark rate for different vehicle types in India.
                      
                  ")),
                    
                    h4(p("Conducted complete Logistics spend analysis and cost-saving by conducting Diagnostic and Descriptive analytics, 
                        identifying process gaps for leading Pharmaceutical, Cement, and metal companies.
                  ")),  
                    h4(p("Developed capacity planning tool using linear programming algorithm which helps complete 
                        allocation within minutes replacing the majority of manual allocation.
                  ")),  
                    h4(p("Developed dashboards for various clients in Excel and R shiny for tracking, analyzing, 
                        and displaying Key Performance Indicators to monitor the health of the business.
                  ")),
                    h4(p("Conducted complete process audit for a large packaged food company implementing tools 
                      like As-Is mapping, To-be Mapping, Time and Motion Study, conducting GAP analysis.
                  ")),
                    h4(p("Exploratory analysis: Using statistical tools like R Programming, Microsoft Excel, 
                        and visualization tools like Tableau, Power BI.
                  ")),
                    h4(p("  Carried out work as per project plan agreed with the client, training at the client
                        location, hand-holding client teams on improvement areas, coordinate and conduct reviews.
                  ")),
                    
                    br(),
                    br(),
                  tags$img(src='damco.png',height=80,width = 150,style = 'float:right;'),    
                  h1(p("Damco India Pvt Ltd - Maersk Group")),
                  h4(p("April 2017 - June 2019")),
                  h3(em(p("Supply Chain Executive - Customer Associate"))),

                    h4(p("Responsible for managing, controlling all SCM operations activities on the pan-India basis
                    for Walmart, to deliver optimal operations performed in accordance with the area business strategy and
                        agreed customer SLA.
                  ")),

                    h4(p("Designing of the dashboard for monthly and quarterly analysis on volume and
                      performance across all the regions and planning future strategies.
                    ")),

                    h4(p("Handling logistics movements of FCL and LCL shipments for exports from India and
                        Sri Lanka to USA, Canada and Mexico.
                    ")),

                    h4(p("Managing and coordinating with various internal and external stakeholders to maintain
                        the service levels required by the customer.
                    ")),

                    h4(p("Responsible for training and onboarding of vendors, monitoring vendor KPI and
                      rating them as per their performance.
                    ")),
                  
                  br(),
                  br(),
                  tags$img(src='ISL.png',height=120,width = 150,style = 'float:right;'),
                  h1(p("Intellvisions Software Limited")),
                  h4(p("April 2014 - May 2015")),
                  h3(em(p("Junior Software Engineer"))),
                  
                  h4(p("Responsible for Installation of Kiosk, OptiQ machines & making it run live as per client's SLA.
                  ")),
                  h4(p("Run queries in SQL database performing CRUD operations.
                  ")),
                  h4(p("Visiting installation sites & to provide expert technical support to site engineers 
                    during escalation & complex cases.
                  ")),
                  h4(p("Testing and verifying that the implemented solution meets the requirement as per RFP.
                  ")),
                  
                  h4(p("Conduct product training sessions for site engineers and newly joining candidates.
                  ")),
                  
                  h4(p("To build & maintain Software repository documentation, instruction manuals, specifications.
                  "))),
                  
                  tabItem(tabName = "certifications",
                  
                  h1(p("CERTIFICATIONS"),align = "center"),
                  br(),
                  br(),
                  tags$img(src='simplilearn.png',height=120,width = 120,style = 'float:right;'),
                 
                  h3("Tableau Desktop 10 Associate"),
                  h4("Simplilearn"),
                  h4("Credential: 1740409"),
                  
                  br(),
                  br(),
                  tags$img(src='CII.png',height=120,width = 120,style = 'float:right;'),
                  h3("Supply Chain Management Executive"),
                  h4("Confederation of Indian Industry"),
                  h4("Credential: SCMEXE/2015/0460"),
                  
                  
                  br(),
                  br(),
                  tags$img(src='Axelos.png',height=120,width = 120,style = 'float:right;'),
                  h3("PRINCE2 Foundation and Practitioner Certificate in Project Management"),
                  h4("AXELOS Global Best Practice"),
                  h4("Credential: GR656075300MT"),
                  
                  
                  br(),
                  br(),
                  
                  tags$img(src='AIQM.png',height=120,width = 120,style = 'float:right;'),
                  h3("Lean Six Sigma Green Belt"),
                  h4("Asian Institute of Quality Management"),
                  h4("Credential: A-4229"),
                  
                  br(),
                  br(),
                  
                  tags$img(src='mdb.png',height=120,width = 120,style = 'float:right;'),
                  h3("MongoDB Basics"),
                  h4("MongoDB University"),
                  h4("Credential:https://university.mongodb.com/course_completion/1b93b92b-57a0-40df-8846-32c51e5"),
                  
                  br(),
                  br(),
                  
                  tags$img(src='dgm.png',height=120,width = 120,style = 'float:right;'),
                  h3("Regulation of Transport of Dangerous Goods By Sea - IMDG Code (Amendment 38-16)"),
                  h4("IMDG"),
                  h4("Credential:IMDG-D-0145-18")
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyServer(function(input,output, session){
        
})
```

Comment: The images don't seem to be in `www`: https://mayanktripathi.shinyapps.io/RESUME/_w_3359c0cd/CII.png

Comment: I have added the images in www folder, just renamed the folder again, have named it with small caps www. Still the issue persists.

Comment: I meant the adress is not looking in `www`, but in `_w_3359c0cd`

Comment: @Waldi sir, while running the app in local computer i can view the images, just not happening, i tried all my wits saw many suggestions just not happening for me. I am not an expert in R programming, just learning and doing stuff on my own.

Comment: I fear I can't help more because I never used shinyapps.io. Others will certainly be able to share experience on this.

Comment: Have you tried adding `www/` before every picture ? This work on shinyapps.io

Comment: @Gowachin, for example if i am naming my image as "apple", are you saying to add "www/apple" as the name of the image?

Comment: I have my website here  - https://shahronak.shinyapps.io/my_shiny_app/ and the code for it is present here https://github.com/shahronak47/my_shiny_app . Check if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I inspected your code in the browser and noticed that the only image that is sourced is the only one that is being displayed:
[image]

Double-check to make sure that the images are in the www/ directory of the app and you are sourcing them all using:

```
src = "www/[filename]"
```

Also, you can try to render the image on the server-side using renderImage: Check out [this article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14.2/renderImage.html) on rendering images in shiny apps.

Furthermore, there is a [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/resumer/resumer.pdf) for creating resumes in R that is powered using latex that might be worth checking out.